# How to use debugging identifiers for functions in Swift to console?

Tags: swift, debugging

Noticed that we are supposed to use #function, #line in swift 2.2 instead of **function**, etc. but nothing is printing. I tried cleaning build and build folder and still nothing.

I used this from Apple documentation:

```
func logFunctionName(string: String = #function) {
        print(string)
    }

func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        logFunctionName()
```

I also tried #line and it didn't work. Anybody have a clue? Thanks!

EDIT
Noticed it works for most of my projects but not one specific one.

Answer (score 0):

You should declare the function parameter as an omitted external parameter with a  default value.

```
func logFunctionName(string: String, _ function: String = #function) {
    print("\(function): \(string)")
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        logFunctionName("test")
    }
}
```

This will print `viewDidLoad(): test`

Answer (score -1):

You should use this function to log

```
func DLog(message: String, function: String = #function) {
    print("\(function): \(message)") 
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work. Also, not sure how that is different than the Apple solution other than adding a string message?

Comment: Where do you add this function?

Comment: func DLog(message: String, function: String = #function) {
        print("\(function): \(message)")
}

in other function you want print log
DLog("this's function")},